# Dynamic type model binding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm currently working on a content editor that can be used for multiple types of content, where a developer could specify their own model.  For example, a model might look like this:

```
public class ImageWithCopyWidgetModel : WidgetModel, IWidgetModel
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageAltText { get; set; }

    public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    public string BodyContent { get; set; }
}
```

On the editor side, I have a view model that looks like:

```
public class EditContentViewModel<TModel> where TModel : IWidgetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TModel WidgetModel { get; set; }
}
```

I have the binding on the GET/form display side working fine. My issue comes with getting the model binder to accept the data on the `POST`?  I've tried the following, but each returns `null` for `model.WidgetModel`:

```
// Option 1
EditContent(int pageId, int id, EditContentViewModel<dynamic> model)

// Option 2
EditContent(int pageId, int id, EditContentViewModel<object> model)

// Option 3
EditContent(int pageId, int id, EditContentViewModel<IWidgetModel> model)
```

Note, for testing purposes, I tried explicitly setting the type of `WidgetModel` to a concrete class (the `ImageWithCopyWidgetModel` noted above) and that works.

I'm really trying to avoid having to use `Request.Form` here as its going to limit future plans for this implementation.

Comment: Problem is that when you POST your model to api - type of model is (usually) not encoded anywhere. You usually post something like : `{Id: 1, Name: "name", WidgetModel: {... }}`, but it's impossible (in general) to deduce type of your model from that info.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is not possible, at least out of the box. On post, all the modelbinder has is a bunch of key-value pair string. What informs its decision about how to bind those values to something useful is the action param(s). Specifically, it has no way of knowing that it should *actually* create an instance of `ImageWithCopyWidgetModel` when you're binding to `EditContentViewModel`.

Also, the modelbinder is designed to discard values it doesn't know what to do with. That means that it's unfortunately not even possible to cast to `ImageWithCopyWidgetModel` after the fact, because all properties not present on `EditCopyViewModel` would have been discarded by that point.

Your best bet is a custom model binder, but the implementation of that is too broad for the scope of Stack Overflow. I suggest you refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

Comment: Thanks @chris-pratt.  I was afraid this might be the case.  I'll take a look at building a custom model binder.